# I want to make the second function await the first one to complete but I can’t think of syntax to it

Tags: javascript

I want to make the second function await the first one to complete but I can’t think of syntax to it.

```
 function rr(){
        gr1.innerText = niz.splice(niz[Math.floor(Math.random()*niz.length)],1)
        gr2.innerText = niz.splice(niz[Math.floor(Math.random()*niz.length)],1)
        dl1.innerText = niz.splice(niz[Math.floor(Math.random()*niz.length)],1)
        dl2.innerText = niz.splice(niz[Math.floor(Math.random()*niz.length)],1)
    }

       function reset(){
        niz = ["jd","dv","tr","ct","pt","s","ss","os","dv","dd","jj","dvv","trr","ctt","pett","ssss","sds","ds"]
    }
```

Comment: Call `reset` from `rr`?

Comment: You could call `reset()` after `dl2.innterText = ...`

Comment: I've managed to solve it, code was ok but I made a mistake in coding my random words generator, thank you all for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can implement simple callback from first function and let second function depend on the callback. This way second function will only load when first function's loading is complete.

Refer this : https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

The functions above are synchronous functions, which means that they run synchronously, and don't let the main thread continue until they finished their work. So if you call the `rr` function, and then the `reset` function, `reset` will wait until `rr` finishes executing and only after that, will start running as well.

Asynchronous functions have the keyword `async` before `function` like this:

```
async function myFunction() { ... };
```

In your code, you don't need to use asynchronous functions, as you don't make any requests from another server. Asynchronous functions are not stopping the main thread from executing, by running in the background. They are used on loading large files, gathering data, and other operations that take a lot of time.